# Print only the lines that contain a specific value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have this array in PHP 5.2.3 :

```
$a = array (
    array("a","c","1");
    array("b","a","2");
    array("a","b","3");
    array("b","b","4");
    array("a","a","5");
);
```

and I would like to "select" (or create a new array) only the rows that have the first element "a". Like this :

```
"a","c","1"
"a","b","3"
"a","a","5"
```

How can I do this ?

**EDIT :**

```
<?php
    $a = array (
        array("a","c","1"),
        array("b","a","2"),
        array("a","b","3"),
        array("b","b","4"),
        array("a","a","5"),
    );

    $result = array_filter(
        $array,
        'testFirst'
    );

    print_r($result);
?>
```

I get this error `Warning: array_filter() [function.array-filter]: The first argument should be an array in C:\wamp\www\keySearch\test.php on line 13`

**FINAL EDIT :**

```
<?php
    $a = array (
        array("a","c","1"),
        array("b","a","2"),
        array("a","b","3"),
        array("b","b","4"),
        array("a","a","5"),
    );

    function testFirst($value) {
        return($value[0] == 'a');
    }

    $result = array_filter($a, testFirst);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Besides suggesting updating to a supported version of PHP, perhaps [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a callback function that tests the value of the first element in each callback value

Comment: Loop over the array and check if the first element of each array is `'a'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function testFirst($value) {
    return($value[0] == 'a');
}

$result = array_filter(
    $a,
    'testFirst'
);
```

Comment: I have tried this but I get this error **Warning: array_filter() [function.array-filter]: The first argument should be an array in C:\wamp\www\keySearch\test.php on line 13**

Comment: You have an array, your variable is `$a`, use that as the first argument for array_filter().... see edit

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it manually:

```
$ret = array();
foreach($a as $k => $v)
{
    if ($v[0] == "a")
        $ret[] = $v;
}
print_r($ret);
```